# Are IAM policies transferred when migrating a project from "No organization" to an organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I can't seem to find an answer to this question. I reviewed [the special considerations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#migrating_projects_no_org) for migrating "No organization" projects but they don't touch on this.

The migration guide says for any migration:

> Any policy that is applied directly to the project will still be attached after the migration is complete. Applying policies directly to the project is a good way to verify that the correct policies are applied from the moment the move is complete.

Are the IAM policies of "No organization" projects implicitly "applied directly to the project"?

Comment: The simple answer is yes. However, due to inheritance, the new organization might affect existing IAM policies.

Comment: @JohnHanley Will the principals (that aren't aren't listed here: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#permissions_move) migrate to the new organization or do they have to be added manually before the migration? The guide is ambiguous on this.

Comment: Once you move a project into an organization, you will need to add appropriate IAM users to the organization level IAM.

Comment: @JohnHanley Does this mean services/resources deployed by IAM users that aren't in the destination organization before the migration could potentially malfunction?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. Users with permission within the project will still work However, once you move into an organization, there are new sets of permissions (IAM roles) that you should add to some identities for certain features.